# Gremlin can find an edge, but not traverse it

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm developing an app built on an Azure Cosmos database through gremlin. Until now, everything went smoothly, but I recently encountered an interesting situation.

To summarize, I have three vertices:

- Two of them represent a taxonomy element, "taxoElt_cgt_11124_2016" (let's name that one T1) and "taxoElt_scian_334_2017-v3" (T2) The third is a datapoint representing the intersection of these two elements, "11124|2016_SCIAN-334|2017-v3" (let's name it D).

There are two edges here, linking T1 to D and T2 to D, both labeled "hasDatapoint". The first one works entirely as expected, but things get weird for the second one.

More precisely, I can see both edges (as expected) through the query :

```
g.V('D').inE()
```

but when I do :

```
g.V('D').inE().outV()
```

I only see T1, where I should see both. Furthermore,

```
g.V('T2').outE('hasDatapoint')
g.V('T2').out('hasDatapoint')
```

both don't return anything.

What is very strange here is that I can see both edges in the first query, and both are completely identical (apart from their id and `outV`), but somehow, only one of them is visible in any other query.